# Confused about the algebra of continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, continuity

> Provide an example (or explain why the request is impossible) of a pair of functions $f$ and $g$ neither of which is continuous at $0$ but such that $f(x)g(x)$ and $f(x) + g(x)$ are continuous at $0$;

What we know definitionally is that

$$\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)g(x)=f(0)g(0) \\ \lim_{x\to 0} f(x) + g(x)=f(0) + g(0)$$

(We know that $x=0$ is not an isolated point of their domains because a function is trivially continuous at those). Provided that $f(0)g(0) \neq 0$, we could use the fact that a quotient of continuous functions is a continuous function:

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)+ g(x)}{f(x)g(x)}= \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{f(x)} + \frac{1}{g(x)} \stackrel{\text{???}}{=} \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{f(x)} + \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{g(x)}$$

If we knew those functions were continuous, we'd know the request is impossible. But you can distribute limits only if you previously know they exist. So I'm totally lost.

How can I approach these exercises that deal with the algebra of continuous functions?

Comment: What about $f(x) = 0$ for $x<0$, $f(x) = x+1$ when $x\geq 0$, $g(x) = 0$ when $x\geq 0$, $g(x) = -x+1$ when $x<0$. Then $f(x)g(x) = 0$ and $f(x)+g(x) = |x|+1$.

Comment: or $f(x)=0$ if $x\le0, 1 $ otherwise, and $g(x)=1-f(x)$

Answer (score 1):

Here is one example:

Let $f(x)=2$ if $x<0$ and $f(x)=1/2$ if $x\geq 0$. Let $g(x)=1/2$ if $x<0$ and $g(x)=2$ if $x\geq 0$.

Then 
$$f(x)+g(x)=5/2 \qquad x\in\mathbb{R}\tag{1}$$
$$f(x)g(x)=1 \qquad x\in\mathbb{R}\tag{2}$$

We can cook other examples such that (1) $f(0^-)=g(0^+)$ and $f(0^+)=g(0^-)$; (2) $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are continuous for $|x|>0$.

Answer (score 1):

Take
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
-1 & (x<0) \\
+1 & (x\geq0) \\
\end{cases}
\quad\quad\quad\quad
g(x) = -f(x)
$$
Neither $f$ nor $g$ is continuous (they have a dicontinuity at $0$).

Then
$$
f(x)+g(x) \equiv 0,
\quad\quad\quad\quad
f(x) \, g(x) \equiv -1.
$$
Both of these are continuous.